# Node.js - Maximum call stack size exceeded only for one User

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a live feeds project which is integrated on multiple clients websites.
Backend is in Node JS and frontend is in React JS.
The tool fetches live feeds from all social websites. 
However, i keep getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" for only one of the user. The code works in more than 20 websites but give this error on only one.
I tried to increase Node.js stack-size but still the same issue for the client.
Can you please suggest why this errors occurs or what are the possibilities to track this error.

Comment: Are clients able to host their server node.js code?

Comment: This error is adequate reaction for infinite loop in the code.

Comment: but the same loop works for all other hosts.

Comment: I was getting similar issue,it was fixed after changing stable version of mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

This error is adequate reaction for infinite recursion loop in the code.

Example:

```
(function fib(n) {
   return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
})(5);
```

Solution is add correct recursion finalization:

```
(function fib(n) {
   if (n < 2) return 1;
   return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
})(5);
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I will try to find and correct this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Sounds like an infinite loop for me. Did you check your code, maybe there is a function which does not return for some values passed in?